# Set variable as ajax url

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to set **ajax URL to variable res**.

Variable res is a combination of different strings.
You can have a look at the code.

HTML

```
    <form id="frm1">
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="" placeholder="Update Location">
    </form>
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" onclick="loadWeather()"type="button">
 Search 
</button>
```

Here I'm trying to fetch the text in the form.

.js

```
window.onload = loadWeather();

var part = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
var a = encodeURI(part);
var b = document.getElementById("frm1");
var text = b.elements[0].value;
var urll = "&units=metric&appid=MYKEY";
var c = encodeURI(urll);

var res = a + text + c;

function loadWeather() {
    $.ajax({
        url: res,
```

When I check the value of res in console it's shown as undefined.

One more error is Cannot read property 'elements' of null
    at blog.js:7

All I want is that the final URL must be equal to something like this-

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=FORMDATA&units=metric&appid=MYKEY

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error in your code. In the first line:

```
window.onload = loadWeather();
```

You are making a call to function `loadWeather` on page load, which means this function will be called immediately before any other javascript code. At this time you haven't assigned the `res` variable yet, which will be filled later after calling the function.

You will have to call the function after variable assignment. For example, something like this will work:

```
 // window.onload = loadWeather();
 var part = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
 var a = encodeURI(part);
 var b = document.getElementById("frm1");
 var text = b.elements[0].value;
 var urll = "&units=metric&appid=MYKEY";
 var c = encodeURI(urll);

 var res = a + text + c;
 loadWeather()
 function loadWeather() {
     console.log(res)
 }
```